# how to know what specific files a program is downloading or uploading?

Tags: networking, internet, firewall

this is my first question here 
I use Google Chrome as a browser, when I download something using IDM i noticed the speed doesn't get even 25% of my full speed but when i close chrome, it changes quickly and reach the full speed ? 
how does chrome can affect the downloading speed even i just opening a blank page ? this happens every time 
I tried to use GlassWire as a firewall it turned out that chrome always downloading something or uploading (while opening only a blank page not even surfing websites) and how to know what it's uploading ? or where does it download these things ?

Comment: It is not necessarily downloading to file. But if it is a file, there are utilities to check for open files and associates them with the process that uses them (in Linux (and OSX?): `lsof`, and in Windows, possibly some SysInternals utility. But it may be time to review your list of Chrome add-ons.

Comment: AdBlock - Dominoes - IDM Integration Module -Pop up blocker for Chrome™ - these are my extensions

Comment: If you just open Chrome or Firefox, you can see they are connected to some websites. But that traffic is too low to interfere IDM download.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the destination IP addresses and consumed bandwidth for each network connection with the built-in [Resource Monitor](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/use-resource-monitor-to-monitor-network-performance/).

Unfortunately it's impossible to see file names or exact plugin that creates the connection, but sometimes you can guess it form the IP address:

- try Whois, sometimes you can get the IP address block owner's name from it
- try nslookup, probably the reverse DNS PTR record will be meaningful